# What is [code-cleanup] for?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I just stumbled across a CodeReview.SE type question tagged [code-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-cleanup).

There's only 218 questions, but is this the intended use? I would think most of them would get  referred on to CR if they were of good quality.

The other use I noticed a handful of times on a quick browse was for questions regarding `cleanup()` type functions. If that's the intended use.. does it really need its own tag?

- Is it useful; should be kept?
- If so, adding a wiki would avoid this mix of use.

Comment: Its intended use was probably on questions asked long before Code Review was only [a twinkle in RobertPitt's eye](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review).

Comment: It's a meta tag, suitable for burnination.