# It's time for [code-cleanup]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

I've stumbled across the [code-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-cleanup) tag and I'm not quite sure if it really is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Just by looking at how the tag is worded seems off-topic as any code cleanup seems to be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)  as long as it on-topic over there.

The tag wiki describes that it is used for cleanup of resources and not for code:

> Code cleanup refers to the act of writing code so that it cleans up leftover data structures and other unwanted materials from memory and the filesystem. It is not the same as refactoring code, which involves making the source code itself easier to understand, maintain, and modify.

But it then contradicts itself in the detailed section:

> Code cleanup can also refer to the removal of all comments from source code, or the act of removing temporary files after a program has finished executing.

I've also seen [this old unanswered question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268617/what-is-code-cleanup-for) which addressed the same issue, but it didn't gain a lot of attention (The only comments were from two mods, which suggested burnination).

I suggest [code-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-cleanup) to be burninated.

To follow the official process here are the *Criteria for Burninantion*:

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

- As mentioned in the first part of this post, the name of the tag itself is off-topic, as cleanup of code is not a specific problem (or even too specific?).
- The tag wiki contradicts itself in saying that *code-cleanup*:

  1. *code-cleanup* is about cleaning up of resources (like memory, leftover data structures, etc), and not refactoring of source code. **(Paraphrased first part of tag-wiki)**
  2. *Code cleanup can also refer to the removal of all comments from source code or the act of removing temporary files after a program has finished executing.* **(copy of second part of tag-wiki)**
  3. It may as well stand for the *code cleanup* tool in Visual Studio as mentioned in a [comment by Luuklag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383165/is-code-cleanup-on-topic#comment689745_383165) **(Not mentioned in tag-wiki)**

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Two of the three mentioned points in **1.** are on-topic.

- Resource cleanup is a real thing and there are many questions out there already covering that topic.
- Also questions about tools used by programmers are on-topic.
- Refactoring of code though is almost always blatantly off-topic. Code Review may be the better place to ask such questions, but it of course should conform to their standards too.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

- If the tag is left as-is, then no. Someone reading the tag *now* almost certainly will think that the question is about refactoring and cleaning of source code.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

- As mentioned in **1.**: No. It can mean resource cleanup, source code formatting, or even be a tool from Visual Studio.

---

I would suggest:

1. Closing / Deleting questions about source-code cleanup
2. Retagging questions about *Cleaning up of resources* to the already existing tag: [resource-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-cleanup) (copying of the first paragraph of the tag-wiki of [code-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-cleanup) to [resource-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-cleanup) may be desired, as the latter lacks a description).
3. If many questions remain, talking about the visual studio function, a new tag may be created.

Comment: There is a feature in Visual Studio named this way as far as I can tell from the tagged questions. So it **might** have a use-case there

Comment: @Luuklag I am sadly not familiar with visual studio, but from a quick google search it just seems to be about formatting code, right? Also there is already a tag for that: `[code-formatting]` (Which also seems somewhat offtopic though).

Comment: Questions about programming tools are on-topic. I don't see why there would need to be a tag specifically for a code formatting feature though. I can scarcely imagine that hundreds of unique questions will be asked about it.

Comment: @Luuklag We'll need to quantify that then and make a specific tag if need be. This tag is way too meta as-is

Comment: @Machavity from a quick search there seems to be ~400 questions tagged [code-cleanup] of which ~60 contain visual studio, I haven't looked into them in detail though

Comment: @Machavity, CC Lino, thats why I put emphasis on might, I'm no expert in that field

Comment: It might be meaningful to at least separate source clean-up (indention, style, removing old debug code etc) from resource clean-up (freeing allocated resources and handles). When I hear code clean-up I think of the former, not the latter.

Comment: @Lundin the former seems off-topic isn't it? SO is here to solve problems, not help people how to indent code correctly. Whereas the latter seems completly on-topic, we even have a tag for it `[resource-cleanup]`, which lacks a tag wiki though

Comment: @Lino As long as a coding style question isn't subjective or opinion-based, it is perfectly on-topic. For example how to indent code while following a certain specific coding standard.

Comment: @Lundin If the code is erroneous due to wrong formatting then it would be suited, like with the indentation in Python, but next to that I can't think of a question which wouldn't be subjective or opinion based. Because coding standards are also just guidelines and not required by the language syntax. I've also found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308274/393786) which somewhat supports my point

Comment: @Lino: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info and then edit your post to conform to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination